# How to save last overlapping row in a queue and release older row in laravel queue

Tags: laravel, queue, overlapping

I have a main queue in Laravel and I want to run that queue every 10 minutes and split its contents into smaller queues.
In small queues, some data have updates and I want the last update to be entered in the small queue and the old updates to be removed from the queue.
Thanks for pointing me to how to keep the latest updates in small queues and delete older updates

Comment: Wanting to run something every 10 minutes doesn't sound appropriate for the queue. Maybe you should [schedule](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling) it instead

Comment: yeah i use schedule, but how to release older row overlapping not new row overlapping